Feudal Japan TV series
I'm looking for the title of a TV series probably from the 80s. It's about a British captain coming to feudal Japan with his crew, but Japan is already influenced by Spanish missionaries and in Europe, England and Spain are at war.
Of course there is lots of samurai stuff going on and people getting executed for no particular reason. But the most memorable thing is that the Japanese people only speak Japanese even though it's an English TV series and the only one able to translate English to Japanese is the Spanish missionary. Also a crew member is being tortured by being fried in the beginning.
Any hints on the movie title, actors, pictures, etc. are highly welcome.

Sounds like Shogun
Extract from Wikipedia:

Shōgun is an American television miniseries based on the namesake novel by James Clavell. The miniseries was broadcast over five nights, between September 15 and September 19, 1980, on NBC in the United States. To date, it is the only USA TV show/miniseries to be filmed entirely on location in Japan. Sound stage shots were also done in Japanese studios.

There were no Spanish, but Portuguese and the Jesuits.
From the Plot description:

The story is based on the adventures of English navigator William Adams. The series follows Pilot John Blackthorne's experiences in Japan in the early 17th century. After his ship, the Erasmus, is wrecked along the coast of Japan, Blackthorne must juggle his identity as an Englishman associated with other Europeans, namely Portuguese traders and Jesuit priests, and the Japanese culture into which he is thrust. ...

From the reception:

The Japanese characters speak in Japanese throughout, except when translating for Blackthorne. The original broadcast did not use subtitles for the Japanese portions. As the movie was presented from Blackthorne's point of view, the producers felt that "what he doesn't understand, we [shouldn't] understand"


At least parts can be seen at Youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYON1TPAQHs Parte 1 - 4. ~ 2h

I also found DVD with the film.

Yes this is it, but how can it be a mini series? I remember having watched it for at least 6h and it was far from complete. The trek just left its home castle towards Edo(?) I guess. Things just started to get rolling...

See my edit for youtube and DVD

@user7249 - it was a miniseries, only 5 episodes, but a running time of 547 minutes (according to wikipedia).
